# SQL query to group message conversations

Tags: sql

I am trying to select the most recent record between 2 users based on a to_number and a from_number and created date/time.

Once the record is found, display the message and time stamp. As long as either the to_number or from_number have the same pairing, then that is the message I want to display.

I'm really getting stuck on finding unique to/from OR from/to records with the same number combinations AND that haven't been listed before.

My data:

```
Messages table:
"id","to_number","from_number","message","created_at","dm_user_id"
"1","7325551212","5705551234","new update","2011-12-17T11:26:33-05:00","1"
"2","5705551234","3015551212","next update","2011-12-17T11:26:53-05:00","1"
"3","6095559876","4695551212","trying messages.","2011-12-19T19:20:47-05:00","2"
"4","5705551234","4155551212","did i get this?","2011-12-19T20:04:40-05:00","1"
"5","9075551212","5705551234","Where did this go?","2011-12-19T20:05:51-05:00","1"
"6","9075551212","5705551234","testing","2011-12-19T20:12:53-05:00","1"
"7","3015551212","5705551234","Are you here ","2011-12-19T20:13:34-05:00","1"
"8","6175554567","4695551212","test from app","2011-12-19T22:51:32-05:00","2"
```

From the above data, I only want the following records, listed newest to oldest.

NOTE: Not all records will be returned because there are duplicate to/from combinations.  For example, id 2 and id 7 are messages between the same 2 numbers. Only the most recent will be returned, id 7.

Another example is id 5 and id 6 - they are both to/from the same numbers so only the most recent is returned, id 6.:

for dm_user_id=1

```
"3015551212", "Hello",           "2011-12-19T20:13:34-05:00"  # id 7
"9075551212", "testing",         "2011-12-19T20:12:53-05:00"  # id 6
"4155551212", "did i get this?", "2011-12-19T20:04:40-05:00"  # id 4
"7325551212", "new update",      "2011-12-17T11:26:33-05:00"  # id 1
```

for dm_user_id=2

```
"6175554567", "test from app",    "2011-12-19T22:51:32-05:00"  # id 8
"6095559876", "trying messages.", "2011-12-19T19:20:47-05:00"  # id 3
```

I'm trying different combinations of GROUP BY and DISTINCT, but not getting the results I'm looking for.

```
select * from messages where dm_user_id = 1
group by to_number, from_number

select * from (
select DISTINCT to_number, from_number dm_user_id
from messages) where dm_user_id = 1
```

Comment: Do you have a table of users that has `dm_user_id` and `phone_number` as a relationship, or does that relationship only exist in the `messages` table?

Comment: @Eric I have another table called dm_users.  That table has `"id","email","hashed_password","salt","created_at","permission_level","username","phone_number" `

Comment: Do you have the ability to create views inside this database?

Comment: @CapeCodGunny I'm not sure. I'm using postgres on heroku and not fully aware of all of the features provided yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common question, basically you want the most recent message from each number, either TO or FROM, but you don't want duplicates. You may find something useful in this category [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group)

Comment: This works.  adjusted from the above link to fit my data and results in only one combination pair and sorted newest to oldest.

Answer (score 1):

With a `dm_users` table, you want this:

```
select
    m.*
from
    dm_users u1
    cross join dm_users u2
    inner join messages m on
        u1.phone_number in (m.to_number, m.from_number)
        and u2.phone_number in (m.to_number, m.from_number)
where
    u1.dm_user_id = 1
    and u2.dm_user_id = 2
order by
    m.created_at desc
```

Comment: When i run the select, I'm getting back just 1 record.  It's the most recent record, but not getting all of the records.

Comment: I'm getting an error of `Unknown column 'u1.dm_user_id' in 'where clause'` I tried the query on both sqlite and mysql

Comment: Is the user id column in `dm_users` not `dm_user_id`? If not, just change those column names in the `where` clause to the column names.

Comment: I may have given info above that confused the question.  I have each dm_user's phone numbers for info only.  At this point I am only interested in getting a list of unique to_number / from_number combinations back and only the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

The working SQL that returns only 1 most recent message for a given to/from, from/to number pair and sorts with most recent first.  Modified the SQL from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593908/selecting-most-recent-as-part-of-group-by-or-other-solution).

```
SELECT
   fullMessage.id,
   fullMessage.to_number,
   fullMessage.from_number,
   fullMessage.message,
   fullMessage.dm_user_id
FROM
    messages fullMessage JOIN
    (
        SELECT max(id) as MAX_ID, to_number, from_number
        FROM messages WHERE dm_user_id = 1  # this can be changed for any dm_user_id
        GROUP BY from_number, to_number
    ) maxMessage ON maxMessage.MAX_ID = fullMessage.id
ORDER BY fullMessage.id desc;
```